# Access UserControl child controls?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a custom UserControl. That control has a Grid which I can access by name. But I can't seem to access the subcontrols from UserControl's constructor.

I can do:

```
this.LayoutRoot
```

but not

```
this.LayoutRoot.MyChildControl
```

how can I access this control programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you used the `x:Name` attribute: `x:Name="MyChildControl"`, you cen refference it in code behind regardless of nesting.

`x:Name` sets the `FrameworkElement.Name` property (but can be also used on objects other then `FrameworkElement`) and results in creating a field with this name which is assigned to in `InitializeComponent()`.

So you can call simply:

```
this.LayoutRoot...
this.MyChildControl...
```

Note that `FrameworkElement` has a `FindName` method, which will work similarly to what you expected:

```
this.LoayoutRoot.FindName("MyChildControl")
```

Answer (score 1):

By code you can create new object of your UserControl and then you can easily access user control elements by it's name.

```
MyUserControl ctrl=new MyUserControl();

ctrl.LayoutGrid.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

or generally 

ctrl.ChildrenName
```

Answer (score 0):

UserControl's child control can access by `UserControl.Content`. If you want to access your Grid's children, please use `this.LayoutRoot.Children`. You can enumerate this collection.